# Why is the server not giving me any responses?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

so I have a server that is supposed to return a JSON token for authentication. But it isn't returning anything (I have it printing messages to the console), not even an error message. Well mostly, it has sent back an error message once or twice. What I've tried is fleshing out the success complete and error functions. I know that my form elements are being picked up because they print to the console. I've had people confirm the server working with ajax requests, but this won't. I am not posting the servers URL for obvious reasons.

```
$(function()
  {

    $("#login").click(function()
    {
     var username = $("#username").val();
     var password = $("#password").val();
      login(username, password);

    });

       function login(username, password)
       {
       $.ajax
       ({
         url: "/",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: '{"username": "' + username + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
         success: function(data, text, xhr)
         {
           console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(text);

         },
         error: function(xhr, status, error)
         {
           console.log("Error" + xhr + status + error);
         },
          complete: function(xhr, text)
          {
          console.log(xhr.status, text);
          } 
       });

       }

  });
```

In chrome, it gives me no errors. But in firefox:

```
POST file/ HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Error has occurederror jquery.min.js line 2 > eval:58:14
0 error jquery-latest.min.js line 2 > eval:62:13
Complete jquery-latest.min.js line 2 > eval:63:13
OPTIONS XHR addressofserver/ 
XHR Object Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: 
.ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: 
.ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(),
```

`setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType:` `.ajax/v.overrideMimeType(),` 
`statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state:` `.Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then:` `.Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }`

Note that "Complete" and "Error has occured" are strings that I wrote in my code. They both are pointing at Jquery. I know the link to jquery is working because it is grabbing user input.

Also under POST, it says that the content type is text/html although I set it to json, otherwise it seems okay:

```
Vary:   Accept-Encoding
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified:  Fri, 22 Apr 2016 20:10:32 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Etag:   "c6c-531186b4ac855-gzip"
Date:   Fri, 22 Apr 2016 20:18:41 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Content-Length: 1078
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host:   localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

under options it says

```
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method:  POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

It's also printed this under XHR Object when I high light it:

[image]

Update 1:

One of my buttons was refreshing the page before the request was sent. Now I am getting a different error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at */link*. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

What I am trying is adding this to the $.ajax :

```
        crossDomain: true,
       xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
```

I am still getting the same error though.

Comment: Check the network tab in your devtools and see if the request is being made and what it returns

Comment: Other than that, there is not `accept` option in jQuery ajax. (*maybe you want `accepts` but that should be a plainObject and not a string*). Also if your server never times out and a problem occurs there you will not get any info back (*you might want to use the `timeout` options*)..

Comment: "mostly, it has sent back an error message once or twice" --- what were the errors?

Comment: Literally just added them. They are only showing up on firefox but not chrome.

Comment: can u give ur TV or remote ? let me fix it 4 u

Answer (score 0):

Things that can help you to identify the problem source :

- sending a normal post request with `<form>` and `<input>` and check the
  response of the server
- opening the browser dev tools and see if u get
  anything weird
- debug any state of the actual prob

also try to change the `$.ajax` by `$.post`
see method docs here : 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/